# What Regular Expression Can I Use To Search And Replace The Following in MS Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, regex, search, text-editing, text-formatting

I have lots of text in Microsoft Word similar to the following:

> 1 The quick brown 2 fox jumps over 3 the lazy dog.

I need some help to find a regular expression that finds the numbers
and inserts line breaks before them, resulting in the following format:

> 1 The quick brown
>   2 fox jumps over
>   3 the lazy dog.

I would greatly appreciate anyone's help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go into “Find and Replace”, click on “More > >”, and click “Use wildcards”.

(But you already knew that, right?)

Set “Find what” to  `{1,9}([0123456789])`
Note that the first character is a space, and the second character is `{`.

Set “Replace with” to `^p\1`
(Caret, lower-case “P”, backslash, “one”)

- The  `{1,9}` matches a string of between one and nine spaces. 
  This allows multiple spaces in the input; e.g.,

  > 1 The quick brown      2 fox jumps over 4 the lazy dog.
- `[0123456789]`, of course, matches a number (specifically, a digit). 
  You can probably use `[0-9]` instead.
- The `(`…`)` delimit a capture group. 
  We want to capture the digit and ignore the spaces.
- `^p`, of course, is a paragraph break
  (the equivalent of typing <kbd>Enter</kbd>). 
  If you want a line break
  (the equivalent of typing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>),
  use `^l` (lower case “L”).
- `\1` substitutes the first capture group.

So: find a number, and replace it and the preceding spaces
with itself preceded by a break. 
In other words, replace spaces with break before a number.